# Crypto++ | HexEncoder sometimes encodes incorrectly | HexEncoder not working consistently | Undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I have written a simple encrypt & decrypt function and everything works. Except sometimes the `HexEncoder` seems to encode the `cipher` far too way small. Therefore the decryption fails. But this rarely happens. I have isolated the bug to the `HexEncoder` since the log `Mismatch on encoding` is only present when the problem appears. A bad workaround is to call the encrypt function again, which solves the problem. Not sure why, perhaps because of a newly generated IV but this seems unlikely to me.

Am I doing something wrong, undefined behaviour? Or is this a bug from the HexEncoder?

Encrypt function:

```cpp
// Encrypt data.
template <typename Encryption> static inline
int     encrypt(Encryption& m_enc, str_t& encrypted, const str_t& data) {

    // Generate & set iv.
    CryptoPP::byte iv [CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    rand.GenerateBlock(iv, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    m_enc.Resynchronize(iv, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    // Encrypt.
    str_t cipher;
    cipher.resize(data.len() + CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    cipher.len() = data.len() + CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE;
    CryptoPP::ArraySink encrypt_sink(
        (Byte*) cipher.data(),
        cipher.len()
    );
    try {
        CryptoPP::StringSource(
            data.data(),
            true,
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(m_enc, new CryptoPP::Redirector(encrypt_sink))
        );
    } catch (...) {
        return crypto::error::encrypt;
    }
    //print("Cipher 1: ", cipher);

    // Set cipher text length now that its known
    if (cipher.len() != encrypt_sink.TotalPutLength()) {
        print("Mismatch on ciper; expected: ", cipher.len(), " sinked: ", encrypt_sink.TotalPutLength());
    }
    cipher.resize(encrypt_sink.TotalPutLength());
    cipher.len() = encrypt_sink.TotalPutLength();
    //print("Cipher 2: ", cipher);

    // Encode.
    encrypted.resize(cipher.len() * 2);
    encrypted.len() = cipher.len() * 2;
    CryptoPP::ArraySink encode_sink((Byte*) encrypted.data(), encrypted.len());
    try {
        CryptoPP::StringSource(
            cipher.data(),
            true,
            new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
                new CryptoPP::Redirector(encode_sink)
            )
        );
    } catch (...) {
        encrypted.len() = 0;
        return crypto::error::encode;
    }
    print("Encoded cipher 1: ", encrypted);

    // Set encrypted length.
    if (encrypted.len() != encode_sink.TotalPutLength()) {
        print("BUG -> Mismatch on encoding; expected: ", encrypted.len(), " sinked: ", encode_sink.TotalPutLength());
        //str_t shortened;
        //shortened.resize(encode_sink.TotalPutLength());
        //shortened.concat_no_resize(encrypted.data(), encode_sink.TotalPutLength());
        //encrypted.swap(shortened);
        return encrypt(m_enc, encrypted, data);
    }
    encrypted.resize(encode_sink.TotalPutLength());
    encrypted.len() = encode_sink.TotalPutLength();
    print("Encoded cipher 2: ", encrypted);

    // Encode IV.
    str_t encoded_iv;
    encoded_iv.resize(CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE * 2);
    encoded_iv.len() = CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE * 2;
    CryptoPP::ArraySink iv_sink((Byte*) encoded_iv.data(), encoded_iv.len());
    try {
        CryptoPP::ArraySource(
            iv,
            CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE,
            true,
            new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
                new CryptoPP::Redirector(iv_sink)
            )
        );
    } catch (...) {
        encrypted.len() = 0;
        return crypto::error::encode;
    }

    // Set encoded iv length.
    if (encoded_iv.len() != iv_sink.TotalPutLength()) {
        print("Mismatch on encoding iv; expected: ", encoded_iv.len(), " sinked: ", iv_sink.TotalPutLength());
    }
    encoded_iv.resize(iv_sink.TotalPutLength());
    encoded_iv.len() = iv_sink.TotalPutLength();
    print("Encoded IV: ", encoded_iv);

    // Concat IV.
    encoded_iv.concat(encrypted);
    encrypted.swap(encoded_iv);

    return 0;
}
```

Decrypt function:

```cpp
// Decrypt data.
template <typename Decryption> static inline
int     decrypt(Decryption& m_dec, str_t& decrypted, const str_t& data) {

    // Decode.
    str_t decoded;
    decoded.resize(data.len() / 2);
    decoded.len() = data.len() / 2;

    try {
        CryptoPP::StringSource(
            data.data(),
            true,
            new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(
                new CryptoPP::ArraySink((Byte*) decoded.data(), decoded.len())
            )
        );
    } catch (...) {
        return crypto::error::decode;
    }
    // Skip for now.
    m_dec.Resynchronize((Byte*) decoded.data(), CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    // Recovered text will be less than cipher text
    decrypted.resize(decoded.len() - CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    decrypted.len() = decoded.len() - CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE;
    CryptoPP::ArraySink rs((Byte*) decrypted.data(), decrypted.len());

    try {
        CryptoPP::StringSource(
            (Byte*) decoded.data() + CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE,
            decoded.len(),
            true,
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(
                m_dec,
                new CryptoPP::Redirector(rs),
                CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::BlockPaddingScheme::NO_PADDING
            )
        );
    } catch (...) {
        decrypted.len() = 0;
        return crypto::error::decrypt;
    }

    // Set recovered text length now that its known
    decrypted.resize(rs.TotalPutLength());
    decrypted.len() = rs.TotalPutLength();

    return 0;
}
```

Testing:

```cpp
...
str_t data = "Hello World!", encrypted, decrypted;
aes.encrypt(encrypted, data);
aes.decrypt(decrypted, encrypted);
print("Encrypted: ", encrypted);
print("Decrypted: ", decrypted);
```

This are the normal logs (without the bug occurence):

```
Mismatch on ciper; expected: 28 sinked: 16
Encoded cipher 1: 04A2C4FB074F6ACBA996239224BD5F77
Encoded cipher 2: 04A2C4FB074F6ACBA996239224BD5F77
Encoded IV: 02466AEBCF4AC2066CE2E144FC5B71C8
Encrypted: 02466AEBCF4AC2066CE2E144FC5B71C804A2C4FB074F6ACBA996239224BD5F77
Decrypted: Hello World!
```

This are the logs when the bug occurs (with the recursive `encrypt` call commented out):

```
Decoded: Hello World!
Mismatch on ciper; expected: 28 sinked: 16
Encoded cipher 1: C97BFE
BUG -> Mismatch on encoding; expected: 32 sinked: 6
Encoded cipher 2: C97BFE
Encoded IV: 06E05C3DAE3E9D6DAC8971E5C9CA0A1A
Encrypted: 06E05C3DAE3E9D6DAC8971E5C9CA0A1AC97BFE
Decrypted:
```

This are the logs when the bug occurs with the workaround:

```
Mismatch on ciper; expected: 28 sinked: 16
Encoded cipher 1: A0
BUG -> Mismatch on encoding; expected: 32 sinked: 2
Mismatch on ciper; expected: 28 sinked: 16
Encoded cipher 1: 883A8A644E5B50067A
BUG -> Mismatch on encoding; expected: 32 sinked: 18
Mismatch on ciper; expected: 28 sinked: 16
Encoded cipher 1: 58AD2010C761215422F89D42FC2F2396
Encoded cipher 2: 58AD2010C761215422F89D42FC2F2396
Encoded IV: BE361B7D8C9144052220E143AD54CB63
Encrypted: BE361B7D8C9144052220E143AD54CB6358AD2010C761215422F89D42FC2F2396
Decrypted: Hello World!
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what a `str_t` is, but since it has a `.data()` method I assume that returns the underlying `char*`. Since you are not specifying a length in the `CryptoPP::StringSource`, it assumes the input stops at the first NUL byte. For plaintext input this is often fine but cipher data *MAY* contain embedded NULs.

Instead, either pass the length of your `cipher` explicitly:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource(
            cipher.data(),
            cipher.len(),
            true,
            new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
                new CryptoPP::Redirector(encode_sink)
            )
        );
```

Or, better, convert the `str_t` into a `std::string` that knows its own size and pass that as argument.